# How Can I Write a Django Model To Store Details of Users Who Communicate With My Messenger Bot

Tags: python, django, bots, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm currently building a Facebook messenger bot, and I wish to create a Django model to store users who communicate with my bot which is built in Django.

The USER API documentation states how to get a user's details, but I don't know how to incorporate it in my Model. Here is a link to the [USER API.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile)

Comment: Is your bot built on the same Django app? Or do you plan on sending the data to a Django-based API?

Answer (score 1):

Make a get request to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN with sender id received and your page access token string, you will get a JSON containing some basic information about the user.